# Is there a way to find and compare the intensity of a region in two images using cv2?

Tags: python, opencv

I took a before and after image of a hyperpigmented scar and I would like to measure the improvement using opencv.

First, I adjusted the exposure of the two images then I converted them to greyscale and inverted them using:

```
img = Image.open('IMG_7641.jpg').convert('LA')
img.save('greyscale.png')

im = Image.open('greyscale.png').convert('RGB')
im_invert = ImageOps.invert(im)
im_invert.save('inverted.png')
```

I would like to now determine the intensity of the brightest regions in the two images and use it as a way to quantify the improvement in the after pic. I got as far as blurring the images but I'm not sure how to get a value for the intensity.

```
gray = cv2.imread('inverted.png')
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
```

[image: Here's a picture of the stitched before and after images]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Numpy to measure the mean (average) value or you can use it to get just the maximum value in each image.

```
mean = np.mean(blurred)
print('mean:', mean)
max = np.amax(blurred)
print('max:', max)
```

See

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html

Comment: Thank you very much!